# Deploy internal Windows Service with Wix Installer

Tags: installation, service, wix, certificate

I need to deploy a Windows Service with an WIX installer to other PCs in the same company in the background.

The problem is the Unknown Publisher message. The Installer needs to run without user interaction.
I'm aware of certifications, but I can't find resources how to self certify my installer and install this certificate to all pc's.

I need to run an installer without user interaction in the background without interruption caused by the Unknown Publisher prompt

Answer (score 0):

If you run the installer from a process that is already elevated (typically a service account or SYSTEM) and use a command like below it'll be completely silent and no UAC prompt.

msiexec /i your.msi /qn REBOOT=R